# Correct usage of some

Tags: usage

I read the following sentence in my grammar

> Similarly there are other adverbs which which are also compounds of **some a Preposition and a Noun**
>
> example - besides, betimes, today, overboard

I think the bold part is not grammatical. Somebody help me understand this

Comment: I'd understand it as:... compounds that consist of the words *some, a preposition, and a noun*.

Comment: @LucianSava, as in "sometime", "somewhere", "somehow", or "something"? that really kind of makes sense, but needs comma's.

Comment: Yes, indeed @FrankThomas, that's what I thought.

Comment: I've been looking at this again, in the light of the examples.   I think it is most likely an error. It is very hard to parse.  The duplication of "which" is incorrect, The capitalisation is incorrect.  I think this is simply ungrammatical and wrong.

Comment: That quoted passage also uses ***which which***. If everything is exactly as it appears in a grammar book, it's not a good grammar book. Otherwise, I would double-check the exact wording of everything.